# Google Maps: Save markers in an array and then list them

Tags: java, android, google-maps

After the user creates markers on his map, how do I save them + all their properties (lat, long, title, snippet etc) in a structure/array, and then list them all in a separate activity? Should I create an object that associates each marker?

Here is the code for the `MapsActivity`:

```
package com.geekybrackets.virtualtourguide;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public GoogleMap mMap;
    double lat = 0;
    double lon = 0;
    static final int GET_DETAILS = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                lat = latLng.latitude;
                lon = latLng.longitude;

                startActivityForResult(new Intent(MapsActivity.this,newMarker.class), GET_DETAILS);

            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == GET_DETAILS) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String marker_title=data.getStringExtra("title");
                Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                        .title(marker_title));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lon)));

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work with the created markers you can create a `List<Marker>`:

```
private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
```

And then add the created markers to it:

```
Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
   .title(marker_title));
markers.add(m);
```

If you need to pass the markers' values to another `Activity`, as a marker is part of the UI, it's not thought to be persisted, but `MarkerOptions` implements `Parcelable` and you can send it to another activities using intents:

```
List<MarkerOptions> markers = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
    .title(marker_title);
Marker m = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
markers.add(markerOptions);
```

And then, you can send the list using intents:

```
MarkerOptions[] markersArray = markers.toArray(new MarkerOptions[markers.size()]);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("markers", markersArray);
```

Comment: hmm thanks for your detailed response, however, after sending the info through intents i do not wish to start the activity once sent, instead, i want to trigger the activity through a separate button. is that possible when using intents?

Comment: Just keep storing markers on the list and create the intent and start the activity when needed

Comment: @antonio how do you retrieve the markersArray in the other activity? I am really struggling here